# Overlaying a Font Awesome icon over a Bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am having trouble figuring out how to overlay a Font Awesome icon over a Bootstrap thumbnail image and having it scale properly.

This is an example of what my Bootstrap thumbnails are structured like without the Font Awesome icon.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/demoreel.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/soma.png">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/chomsky.png">
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: how is this question related to Font Awesome? Where's your FA codes? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I didn't include any of the Font Awesome codes because I didn't know where to put them.  Some people seemed to put them in a div that was a sibling of the image.  Others nested them in an A tag with the image (if you are going to be using a hyperlink with the image anyways).  I ended up going with the later method and I found it out after digging through a lot of source code for an example website I was looking at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I overlaid the image with a font awesome icon by using CSS to target the  elements and making their position absolute (allowing them to clip with the image).  Then I centered the font awesome icon over the center of the image using top: 50% and left: 50%.  Lastly, I did some fine tuning to get it perfectly centered by adjusting their margins.

```
.thumbnail i {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

This works pretty well for centering over an image as it still stays centered even if the image is scale up from re sizing the browser window.  However, I can't get it to stick on the corner of an image and stay there even after being scaled up.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are some classes available that "increase icon sizes relative to their container":

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

More deets: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#larger